# Import mails from asp.net site to Outlook?

Tags: asp.net, outlook

I have an asp.net app where the user edits a table that generate some reports, and then mails them to his providers.

The client wants to edit this pregenerated emails from Outlook.

There is no Exchange Server.

Should i let download the reports generated, and then use outlook automation from the client side? Can I generate a (.pst?) file that the user could import using Outlook? Or maybe there is completely another way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the level of "editing" required.

One of the things you may want to look it is the VSTO tools to write an outlook plug-in.

Beth Massi has a good blog article on "data controls within outlook add-ins"

[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2009/12/21/build-wpf-data-controls-for-outlook-addins-easily-with-vs2010.aspx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/bethmassi/build-wpf-data-controls-for-outlook-addins-easily-with-vs2010)

There is also a lot of tutorials of the things that can be achieved through VSTO add-ins.

[Msdn Article 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/ee620548%28v=msdn.10%29)

[Msdn Article 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/ee861194%28v=msdn.10%29)

[Msdn Article 3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ff395841%28v=msdn.10%29)

[Line Of Business Applications in VSTO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/bethmassi/migrating-an-outlook-client-to-net-framework-4-in-visual-studio-2010)

Of course these may not be of use to you depending on your circumstances, we would probably need more information on things like:

1. Format of the Report
2. editing being performed
3. Is the report embedded in the email body, or is it an attachment?

Hope this helps

Pete